# How to assign multiple values to multiple ports in VHDL

Tags: variable-assignment, vhdl

I'm writing a small bit of VHDL to rotate the values on eight 7-segment displays.

I have something like this:

```
-- handle the rotation of displays
process(rot_select, d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7)
begin
    case rot_select is
        when "000" => -- rotate by 0
        when "001" => -- rotate by 1
        when "010" => -- rotate by 2
        when "011" => -- rotate by 3
        when "100" => -- rotate by 4
        when "101" => -- rotate by 5
        when "110" => -- rotate by 6
        when "111" => -- rotate by 7
    end case;
end process;
```

Where `rot_select` is a selector to figure out the size of the rotation (first display moves to the second display, etc) and `d0-d7` represent 7-bit vectors that are the inputs of each display.

I was wondering if instead of doing manual assignment like `d1 <= d0; d2 <= d1; ...` every time, I could make it more automatic and use less code? Possibly something like `(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <= (d7,d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6);` or anything that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate assignment is more capable in VHDL-2008, so if you are using VHDL-2008, you can write:

```
(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <= d7 & d0 & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6;
```

Assuming that d0, etc. are declared as `std_logic_vector` or similar.

Note that if you are using VHDL-2008, you can also write the sensitivity list as `(all)`, instead of listing all signals explicitly.

But as Josh writes, a representation as array is more suitable, and that will also work with previous versions of VHDL.  Code could look something like:

```
  ...

  -- 7-segment display
  subtype ssd_t is std_logic_vector(1 to 7);  -- Type for display
  type ssd_arr_t is array(natural range <>) of ssd_t;  -- Type for array of display
  signal d_cur : ssd_arr_t(0 to 7);  -- Current value
  signal d_nxt : ssd_arr_t(0 to 7);  -- Next value
  -- Rotation
  signal rot_select : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);

begin

  -- Handle the rotation of displays
  process (rot_select, d_cur)
    variable idx_cur_v : unsigned(2 downto 0);
  begin
    for idx in d_nxt'range loop
      idx_cur_v := to_unsigned(idx, 3) - unsigned(rot_select);  -- Handles modulo  operation
      d_nxt(idx) <= d_cur(to_integer(idx_cur_v));
    end loop;
  end process;

  ...
```

Comment: Xilinx's synthesizer has bugs around this method.

Answer (score 1):

This problem would be easier if you defined the displays, `d0-d7` as an array of 7 bit vectors instead of as individual signals. Then you would have a signal `display` for example, where `display(0)` corresponded to what is `d0` right now.

Once you have an array of values, then you can use something like a `for...loop` to describe the shifting of the values from one display position to another.

Answer (score 1):

Targets of signal assignments that are aggregates have been legal all along see IEEE Std 1076-1987 8.3 Signal Assignment Statement. Whether or not they've been supported by a particular tool vendor at a particular time is a separate question.

Shift operators have been present since -1993 and are predefined for one dimensional arrays (composites) of type bit (bit_vector).

ror is defined for signed and unsigned composite types in package numeric_std as is to_integer.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity rot_display is
end entity;

architecture foo of rot_display is
    signal d0:          std_logic := '1';
    signal d1:          std_logic := '1';
    signal d2:          std_logic := '0';
    signal d3:          std_logic := '0';
    signal d4:          std_logic := '0';
    signal d5:          std_logic := '1';  
    signal d6:          std_logic := '0';
    signal d7:          std_logic := '1';

    signal rot_select:  std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000"; 
    type rot is array (integer range 0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    constant rotation:  rot :=
            ("111", "110", "101", "100", "011", "010", "001", "000");

begin
TEST:
    process    
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;

        for i in rot'range loop
            rot_select <= rotation(i);  
            wait for 1 ns;          
            (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <=             
                std_logic_vector ( 
                    unsigned'(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) 
                                   ror 
                    to_integer( unsigned(rot_select))           
                );
            wait for 9 ns; 
        end loop;

    -- put (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) back to original position by completing
    -- modulo 8 shift  (total of 32 shifts)

        rot_select <= "100";
        wait for 1 ns;
        (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <=             
            std_logic_vector ( 
                unsigned'(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) 
                               ror 
                to_integer( unsigned(rot_select)) 
        );  
        wait for 9 ns;    

        wait;   -- stops simulation
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Using to_integer can expose you to metavalue issues that this test case is contrived to avoid.

The wait for 1 ns statements insure you see the result of the new rot_select values and not the previous by insuring a simulation cycle occurs first updating rot_select.  The wait for 9 ns statements line up transactions to simulation time.

[image: Waveform from test case]

The last rot_select assignment and subsequent rotation demonstrates the value of  (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) hasn't been altered by completing the next modulo 8 number of shift position shifts.

You could introduce your own ror and integer conversion function to eliminated type conversions.  Your own ror function could accept distance as a standard_logic_vector.

Comment: Do you say that `(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7) <= d7 & d0 & d1 & d2 & d3 & d4 & d5 & d6;` should be legal even in VHDL-2002, and the reason ModelSim reports error on this is due to missing tool support ?

Comment: @MortenZdk - It's worth going through the history of Issue Reports looking for conflicts in interpretations.  The left hand side of your signal assignment is certainly valid.  Any issue would arise from right hand side and whether or "the type of the aggregate must be determinable from the context, excluding the aggregate itself but including the fact that the type of the aggregate must be a composite type" (IEEE Std 1076-1993, 8.4, Signal assignment statement, Para 7).  It looks like valid VHDL to me.  Works for d0,.. as type BIT, the RHS for std_logic requires a qualified expression.

Comment: @MortenZdk The qualified expression because "&" can have overload conflicts between std_ulogic_vector and std_logic_vector, which -2008 cures by making std_logic_vector a resolved subtype.  Any tool that simply complains about the left hand side is probably in error.

Comment: ModelSim in VHDL-2002 mode for `(slv_1, slv_2) <= slv_3 & slv_4;` reports 'Signal "slv_1" is type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR; expecting type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_ULOGIC'.  So based on your comments, it looks like ModelSim lacks support for aggregate targets containing vectors, since ModelSim can handle for example `(sl_1, sl_2) <= slv_1;`.  (slv_* is `std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)`, and sl_* is `std_logic`).

Comment: @MortenZdk library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity MortenZdk is
end entity;
architecture foo of MortenZdk is
    signal slv_1, slv_2:    std_logic_vector(0 to 1);
    signal slv_3, slv_4:    std_logic_vector(0 to 1);
    type element is array (integer range 0 to 1) of std_logic_vector( 0 to 1);
begin
    (slv_1, slv_2) <= element'(slv_3, slv_4);
end architecture;  The element size has to be the same on both sides.

Comment: @MortenZdk, and yes your example (slv_1, slv_2) <= slv_3 & slv_4; puts lie to "Any tool that simply complains about the left hand side is probably in error", ghdl only complains about the left hand side in this case, too.